# how to add react jsx as javascript file type in vim and enable eslinting, auto completions?

Tags: javascript, vim, reactjs, eslint

I have recently started using vim.I want to set up files having `.jsx` extension to be treated as `.js`  java script file in Vim. 
Also I want to enable es-linting, snippets with my `.jsx` files. I have installed following packages in my system

```
npm install -g eslint
npm install -g babel-eslint
npm install -g eslint-plugin-react
```

I have also installed `Bundle 'mxw/vim-jsx'` to support jsx in vim.

Also added following lines in my .vimrc file

```
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['eslint']
let g:jsx_ext_required = 0
```

**Edit**
Found this vim plugin for react snippets:
[Vim-react-snippets](https://github.com/justinj/vim-react-snippets)

Comment: Syntastic supports composite filetypes out of the box, see `:h syntastic-composite`, so installing `vim-jsx` should be enough.  It's hard to tell why it doesn't work for you without a debug trace.  The issue tracker is [here](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I decided to write this tutorial to setup **vim** for **React** development in depth so that beginners find this useful when they start with vim and react.

**Syntax highlighting**

To get the jsx syntax high-lighting to look right in vim, use **[mxw's Vim JSX](https://github.com/mxw/vim-jsx)** plugin.

**Steps to Install mxw/vim-jsx Plugin**

If you use `Vundle`,

---

add following lines in your `.vimrc`:

```
Plugin 'mxw/vim-jsx'
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
```

This plugin depends upon **[pangloss/vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript)** so you need to install that as well.

To install from within vim, use the commands below.

```
:so ~/.vimrc
```

To source changed `.vimrc` configuration file and use it, next

```
:PluginInstall
```

If you use pathogen

---

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/mxw/vim-jsx.git
```

**Enable JSX Syntax Highlighing in javascript files**

Add following lines in your .`vimrc`:

```
let g:jsx_ext_required = 0
```

**Enabling eslint in vim**

You need to install following helper npm packages along with latest **eslint** ( used **2.11.1** at the time of writing ).
Also make sure that you have **node.js** version **4 or above** installed in your system.

**babel-eslint**             -  To support ES6 linting

**eslint-plugin-react**   -  React specific linting rules for ESLint
e.g prevent usage of setState in componentDidMount

```
npm install  --save-dev eslint
npm install --save-dev babel-eslint
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-react
```

I decided to use common practices and conventions used by **AirBnB**, so I installed following packages as well. But You don't need them
If you do not  want to use AirBnB eslint presets.

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-airbnb
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-import
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y
```

---

Create a config file **.eslintrc.json** in your project's root:
(You can use eslint to generate eslint configuration file in intreactive way)

```
eslint --init
```

(If you chose any presets make sure you also install required package for that lint preset)

I extended "airbnb" but overrided some of rules for my project. You can use 
    **"extends": "eslint:recommended"** to enable some common lint rule recommended by eslint
Here is my **.eslintrc.json** file

```
{
    "extends"       : "airbnb",
    "parser"        : "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions" : {
        "ecmaVersion"  : 6,
        "sourceType"   : "module",
        "ecmaFeatures" : {
            "jsx":true
        }
    },
    "env": {
        "browser" : true,
        "node"    : true,
        "jquery"  : true
    },
    "settings":{
        "react":{
            "pragma":"React",
            "version":"15.1.0"
        },
        "ecmascript":6,
        "jsx":true
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "strict": 0,
        "quotes": 0,
        "no-unused-vars": 1,
        "camelcase": 1,
        "no-underscore-dangle": 1,
        "comma-dangle":[1,"never"],
        "indent":["error",4],
        "react/jsx-indent":0,
        "react/jsx-equals-spacing": [2, "always"],
        "no-console":0,
        "max-len":1,
        "no-param-reassign":1,
        "key-spacing": [
              2,
              {
                "align": "colon",
                "beforeColon": true,
                "afterColon": true
              }
        ],
        "no-multi-spaces": [
              2,
              {
                "exceptions":{
                    "VariableDeclarator":true,
                    "ImportDeclaration":true,
                    "JSXAttribute":true,
                    "AssignmentExpression":true
                }
              }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

**Now integrate ESLint with Syntastic Plugin in Vim** 
I decided to use Syntastic with vim for syntax error checking.

```
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['eslint']
```

All set but still there is one issue remaining with Syntastic. 
**Syntastic searches global node_modules instead of local project.**

*One solution will be install all packages eslint, babel-eslint etc globally which definately will not be a good practice.*

**Another solution is**

Define a **npm script** in your **package.json**

```
"eslint": "eslint -c .eslintrc.json"
```

*It will add all the locally installed npm packages in current path, so they will be available for execution.*

And in your `.vimrc` file add

```
let g:syntastic_javascript_eslint_exe = 'npm run eslint --'
```

Here we are invoking linting via npm script from vim.

**Alternative:** use Plug **'mtscout6/syntastic-local-eslint.vim'** plugin

**Open error window in vim as you open your file -**

Add following lines to your **.vimrc** to show current lint error (in case any) as you open your file for edit

```
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

**Snipptes and auto-completion**

There are different forks of snippet engines which allow the user to insert snippets by typing the name of a snippet hitting the expansion mapping.

- github.com/SirVer/ultisnips:
  python, supports all snippets in this repo.
- github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate:
  VimL, snipmate-snippets, engine sometimes behaves strange. Supports snippets/*
- github.com/Shougo/neosnippet:
  VimL, supports snippets/* with some configuration.
- github.com/drmingdrmer/xptemplate: Totally different syntax, does not read snippets contained in this file, but it is also very powerful.

I prefer **neosnippet**. Install it in your vim, to enable snippets with **neocomplete** for auto-completion.

Neocomplete is an amazing autocomplete plugin with additional support for snippets. It can complete simulatiously from the dictionary, buffer, omnicomplete and snippets. This is the one true plugin that brings Vim autocomplete on par with the best editors.

See install instructions [here for neocomplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim)

After installing above plugins you need to install one more plugin to enable react specific snippets

```
Bundle 'justinj/vim-react-snippets'
```

See install instructions [here](https://github.com/justinj/vim-react-snippets) for that plugin.

**If all setup done correctly, you have enabled vim  with eslinting, auto completions,  JSX syntax hightlighting for React, with ES6 features !**

Taken from my [blog](http://techcresendo.com/2016/07/01/syntax-highlighting-eslinting-auto-completions-vim-react/) post.

Comment: vim-plug has changed and now you have to set `Plug 'mxw/vim-jsx'
Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'` instead of using `Plugin` as plug function. If not it gives an `E492: Not an editor command` error.

Answer (score 4):

That plugin you installed already [sets](https://github.com/mxw/vim-jsx/blob/master/ftdetect/javascript.vim#L34) the filetype of `.jsx` files to `javascript.jsx` so those files *should* be treated as if their filetype was `javascript` *plus* any `jsx`-related feature provided by that plugin.

I have no idea how to set up Syntastic for jsx, but you can get linting *without* installing such a huge plugin. For that you will need to add the lines below to `after/ftplugin/jsx.vim` to tell Vim to automatically run `eslint` after a write:

```
" see :help 'errorformat'
setlocal errorformat=%E%f:\ line\ %l\\,\ col\ %c\\,\ Error\ -\ %m,%-G%.%#,%W%f:\ line\ %l\\,\ col\ %c\\,\ Warning\ -\ %m,%-G%.%#

" see :help 'makeprg' and $ eslint --help
setlocal makeprg=eslint\ -f\ compact

" run :make % on write
autocmd! BufWritePost <buffer> silent make % | silent redraw!
```

Comment: Do I need any .eslintrc file? I looked on the net that .eslintrc files let you to organize  the linting rules. I added a sample .eslintrc file in my projects root dir. But how to let vim use that file while saving or after writing?

Comment: Vim itself doesn't use that file; eslint does, though. You can [read its documentation here](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#configuration-file-formats).

Comment: My .jsx files are treated as javascript files not as javascript.jsx files but they have jsx syntax highlighting enabled in them(don't know how?). But no problem this is what I wanted. For snippets I have installed [vim-react-snippets](https://github.com/justinj/vim-react-snippets) and its working fantastically.